# Why wont my computer boot from the logical raid volume while installing Windows 7

Tags: boot, motherboard, raid, gpt, efi

I have new computer I built the motherboard is an ASUS Sabertooth 990FX. The motherboard has UEFI instead of normal BIOS.

The problem I have is when I try to install Windows 7 with my motherboards RAID controller enabled and configured my new RAID volume formated with GPT will not boot. It gives my the error about "inserting proper boot media and restarting".

What is odd though is the machine will boot from the disk(s) with not trouble if they are set to use AHCI mode instead of RAID mode which is kind of a problem for me.

Why would it be doing this? Does it have something to do with GPT? Because the RAID tool asks me if I want erase the MBR when I define the RAID. Could it be that the RAID ROM does support booting from GPT even though my board has UEFI support?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have a ticket in with ASUS level 2 tech support about this issue. Hopefully I can find something.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Win7 does not support GPT on the installation medium. And the BIOS (or EFI) tries to execute the MBR regardless of the partition table, that is only a concern to the respective bootloader. Either way, what are you trying to boot? On a freshly formated disk it is pretty normal that your computer complains about missing boot media. Are you sure you have set the boot order to boot from your windows 7 DVD?

Comment: It does support GPT on the boot drive. If I disable the RAID option rom and run with single disk mode it works fine.